# connecting jvectormap to a database accessed by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have this problem:

Javascript declaration:

```
var OCUPARE_CULOARE = 
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/wp-content/themes/seopress/VerifiOcupareHARTA.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {data : codparcela},
            success: function(response) {
            var   OCUPARE_CULOARE1 =  JSON.stringify(response);
            alert (OCUPARE_CULOARE1); 

            }
      });
var ALAAA = JSON.stringify(OCUPARE_CULOARE);
console.log (OCUPARE_CULOARE);
console.log (ALAAA);
```

PHP file:

```
 <?php
 $res9= $_POST['data'];
 global $wpdb;
 $ocupate = $wpdb -> get_results("SELECT Cod FROM Ocupare_Cimitir WHERE Cod 
 LIKE  '$res9%'");
 echo (json_encode($ocupate));?>
```

The main problem it is that I want to attribute the response from php (json format) to a variable in javascript.

Results:

1) "console.log(OCUPARE_CULOARE)" returns: {readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, getResponseHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

2) "console.log (ALAAA);" returns :  {"readyState":1}

3) "alert (OCUPARE_CULOARE1); " returns **EXACTLY WHAT I WANT** to be put in a variable in javascript : [{"Cod":"F01R01L02"},{"Cod":"F01R01L10"},{"Cod":"F01R01L12"},{"Cod":"F01R01L13"},{"Cod":"F01R01L15"},{"Cod":"F01R02L12"},{"Cod":"F01R10L10"}]

Sorry if if the problem it is too easy, but for me is not.

For the last 2 days I've read about asynchronous call of ajax, I really cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ajax calls are asynchronous. This means that the execution will continue with the code after the ajax call, even though the call is not finished yet.

### Solution 1 (callback)

Callbacks are used to tell an async operation what should be executed after the async operation is finished.

```
function getDataFromServer(callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/seopress/VerifiOcupareHARTA.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {data : codparcela},
        success: function (response) {
            callback(JSON.stringify(response))
        }
    });
}

getDataFromServer(function (OCUPARE_CULOARE1) {
    alert(OCUPARE_CULOARE1);
});
```

### Solution 2 (Promise)

Even though the solution with Promise seems to be more verbose, it pays off later on, because it makes it easy to combine asynchronous functions.

```
function getDataFromServer() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/wp-content/themes/seopress/VerifiOcupareHARTA.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {data : codparcela},
            success: function (response) {
                resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
    });
}

getDataFromServer().then(function (OCUPARE_CULOARE1) {
    alert(OCUPARE_CULOARE1);
});
```

### Solution 3 (async/await)

If you don't need to support a wide variety of browsers (specially old ones), async/await can be an option. It looks cleaner and interoperate with `Promise`s. Notice that you can use await only inside an `async` function, that's why in my example I added the function `doSomething`.

```
async function getDataFromServer() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/wp-content/themes/seopress/VerifiOcupareHARTA.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data : {data : codparcela},
            success: function (response) {
                resolve(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        });
    });
}

async function doSomething() {
    const OCUPARE_CULOARE1 = await getDataFromServer();
    alert(OCUPARE_CULOARE1);
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score -1):

Is not better to do the ajax process into a javascript function, and to return the result on success, or to return false if the ajax process is not working.
Thank's to this, you will get the result of your php file if there is no probleme, and you can put an error if the ajax is not working.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get the response from my sql querry into a variable? Because I want a string response or a json. Thank you for the help.